# Set up a Heroku collaboration such that only one person controls what is spent

Tags: heroku

I would like to be able to make apps for clients via Heroku, but I would love it if they could sign up for the billing themselves so I wouldn't have to keep charging them monthly. Creating a team or a collaboration allows me to change the dyno type to whatever I want, charging them an arbitrary amount of money. I was wondering if there's any way to set things up where the person I'm developing for pays the bill, but has full control over what that bill will be, while I can still work on the app. A collaborator setup is almost what I want—you're not allowed to provision payed addons—but for some reason they still allow you to change the dyno type.

Also, I'm not 100% sure if this is the best exchange to be posting this on, please feel free to point me in the right direction.

Comment: This is probably best handled at the contractual level - sign a contract with them, agreeing to a certain level of spend, and make sure you don't exceed it without permission.